# How can I stop Webpack filenames from changing?

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, webpack, vue.js

I am very new to webpack.

I have set up a boilerplate template with `vue-cli`. Currently, when I run `npm run build` my files will compile to the `/dist/build` folder, then split into `js` and `css` folders.

I'm making a WordPress theme, and I'm accessing the files from `<script>` and `<style>` tags. It works... But every time I recompile Webpack via `npm run build`, the file names randomize, adding a string of random characters at the end (making it impossible to reference the files directly from index.php).

Is there a way to stop Webpack from randomizing the filenames? I don't want to have to update my index.php every time I compile. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature -- the idea is that you can allow browsers to cache your js/css as long as possible, but change the actual filename each time you change the file so that browsers won't recognize it and won't use a cached version. But it does require you have a way to update your HTML source with the updated filenames on each build (there are packages to automate this, of course).

But if you don't want to do that you don't have to. webpack's config lets you specify the filename to use for a build. `output.filename` is the config field you use. See [the docs on output here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpful. I like the idea of caching. You mention packages to automate this process -- could you recommend some? The boilerplate has HTML-Webpack-Plugin installed, which does something along those lines. However, when I try implementing it, I get relative paths (i.e. /dist/static...). Obviously, I need an absolute path with a PHP generated URL to be inserted before the relative path. Is there a method that you know of to implement this?

Comment: Removing the hashes from the filenames in the webpack configuration worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Blue_Dragon360 Your assets will always be relative to your publicPath config. Despite the name, publicPath can be a full url, e.g. 'www.mysite.com/' or 'www.mysite.com/js/'. That should give you the URLs you need.